# How to find the members of a project in continuum(build coordinator -user role -adminstrator,user) programmatically?

Tags: apache, continuum

How to find the members of a project in continuum(build coordinator -user role -adminstrator,user) programmatically?
is there any specific API, which I can use? I have checked continuum-xmlrpc-client.1.4.1.jar ,continuum-xmlrpc-api-1.4.1 and continuum-xmlrpc-server.1.4.1

Answer (score 1):

The API to use is `redback-xmlrpc-api-1.4-M3.jar`, which is distributed along with the web application.

You can find some examples in the client implementation here: https://github.com/redback/redback/blob/redback-1.3-M2/redback-xmlrpc/redback-xmlrpc-client/src/main/java/org/codehaus/redback/xmlrpc/client/CommandLineClient.java

The specific example you are looking for is the Role service, where the role are the ones you've described, and the resource is the project name.